# Redux: right way to handle concurrent requests

Tags: redux

I just can't grasp the core concept I guess.

I have a page with contact list. But user can visit the page with contactID in URL, and in this case I should open a popup window with contact info. So, what am I doing:

My `store` looks like:

```
{
    isRequested: boolean, // is initial loading done
    isLoading: boolean,   // is currently loading,
    contacts: {[ key: number ]: IContact} 
    // where key is contact ID and IContact is generic a model
}
```

Open the page and start loading contacts list.
Without waiting for contacts I'm openinig the popup window.

So, how should I handle this situation? The only thing that come to my mind is to create dummy contact if it's not exist in store. Something like:

```
{
    ...,
    contacts: {
        1: {
            isRequested: false,
            isLoading: true,
            isCorrupted: false // in case of bad ID
        }
    }
}
```

And subscribe to state change in popup window, to wait for this contact `isRequested` to change.

And when all contacts loaded - add all contacts without this one, or merge them.

Is it right approach, or is it a better solution do exists?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep contacts empty and simply display a loading screen until the full list is loaded.

So your state looks like

```
{
    isLoading: boolean,   // is currently loading,
    contacts: {[ key: number ]: IContact} 
}
```

and the initial state

```
{
  isLoading: false,
  contacts: {}
}
```

In your view:

- If contacts is an empty object, display nothing.
- On first load (`componentWillMount` in React), load the list of contacts and set `isLoading` to true.
- When `isLoading` is true, display a loading screen.
- When the list is ready, display your information

Comment: I need to show popup window instantly. So, in this case i'm thinking in a right direction? And I'm using angularJS, but this shouldn't be a matter. :)

Comment: Why not display it once the data is loaded ?

Comment: Let's pretend that popup window with user info could be opened on other page. Where all `contacts` not required. So popup window with contact info should know how to fetch itself. Opening the contact will be reaction on click. And user should see reaction on click.

Comment: ok I get it. You can have a look at portals: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html. It allows you to open a popup that is linked to the rest of your state